# Security issues concerning including external code for module

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to implement some external code in my custom module and if I understand correctly (correct me if I'm wrong), you can drop those folders in both sites/all/libraries as well as in sites/all/modules/custom/myModule/libraries.

What would the better security-wise place to include the folder be?

If you can think of another reason why to place it in the first folder or the second, I'm happy to hear it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your web server is set up correctly then both of the paths you've mentioned will have the same permissions (readable but **not** writeable by the server), so they would be equally secure/insecure depending on the rest of your server setup.

I must admit I haven't come across a path like the second one you mention, although I know most contributed modules that have been updated to Drupal 7 use the `sites/all/libraries` folder for storing external code libraries.

Comment: Ok, great thanks! You only confirmed what I already thought. Thanks!

Comment: i recently heard that a `custom` folder in modules is quite common ;)

Comment: @rémy I meant the `/libraries` part of the path...I haven't seen that inside a contrib/custom module folder before :)

Comment: true .. was reading to fast - sorry